# Why aren't my div's aligning horizontally?

Tags: css

I'm working on a navigation header where the logo is on the left side and the navigation on the right side besides it, at the same height. The problem is that for some reason, the right side always gets pushed way down:

```
 <div class="top_wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            right side content goes here
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 .top_wrapper {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
height: 60px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2000;
 }

 .top {
margin: auto;
width: 970px;
 }

 .logo {
margin-top: 15px;
width:250px;
 }

 .menu {
float: right;
font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-top: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is good as is, no need to change anything.

I would suggest the following **CSS**:

```css
.top_wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.top {
    margin: auto;
    width: 970px;
    border: 1px dotted gray; /* for demo only */
    overflow: auto; /* to contain the floats within the parent block */
}
.logo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    float: left; /* float the logo to the left also */
}
.menu {
    float: right;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Rf3yP/

The key is to float the `.logo` element to the left, which takes it out of the content flow.

According to the CSS specification, floated elements are placed as far to the top of the content as possible after any inflow elements that precede them.

In your case, `.logo` preceded `.menu`, to the menu was placed below the logo.

When you float `.logo`, it is placed to the left and top following the inflow content (top of parent container `.top` in this case)  and since there is room on the same line, the `.menu` block is also placed on the same line.

Add `overflow: auto` to `.top` so that any background color/image or border wraps the floated elements (this starts a new block formatting context).

Answer (score 0):

Try replace float:right; with float:left; on .menu and add float:left; to .logo

Heres a jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eD5Br/

```
  .menu {
float: left;
font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-top: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .logo {
margin-top: 15px;
width:250px;
float:left;
 }
```